How to locally test javascript that contains classes that require secure context
EDIT: It looks like I was making a false assumption that the reason why my code was not working (I was getting AudioWorkletProcessor is undefined) was because the context was insecure... but I will leave this question up since the general question and answer is still useful).
On Mac, I am trying to test some website javascript that involves AudioWorkletProcessor.
Apparently this class is "only available in a secure context."
I'm assuming this means that the browser running the javascript that contains it must believe it is secure (https) with a valid certificate.
I am testing using firebase serve which makes the site available at localhost:5000 but it doesn't use or offer https.
As far as I understand my options are:

Use ngrok to create an https tunnel to localhost:5000
Cannot, because it is a paid feature and I don't want to get into that.

Use http-server like this:
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.cert
http-server -S -C server.cert -K server.key -p 5000 ./public


... but this does not work because the cert is not valid, so we would need add the bad cert to my keychain which I also don't like.
Is there some other way to test javascript that uses classes that require a secure context?  Maybe some kind of fake/test browser??
Thanks.

Note regarding your AudioWorkletProcessor thing, it's only exposed in AudioWorklet contexts: https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#ref-for-dom-audioworkletprocessor-audioworkletprocessor%E2%91%A0 You don't create one from scratch, instead your create an AudioWorkletNode which will create the processor on the Worklet side. See the examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor

"Use ngrok to create an https tunnel[...]" it's actually free.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts

Locally-delivered resources such as those with http://127.0.0.1 URLs, http://localhost and http://*.localhost URLs (e.g. http://dev.whatever.localhost/), and file:// URLs are also considered to have been delivered securely.

You can verify this through the window.isSecureContext property.
